# HTML Scrollbars not showing when text is larger then screen

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am making a website that uses numerous DIVs with a 100% height. Now when the text is bigger than the page I want the normal scrollbars to appear. Unfortunately they don't. and with trying `overflow:auto` anywehre, it gets worse and worse.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>&lt;PageTitle&gt; | Anga Designs</title>
<!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/standard.css" />
            <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iefix.css" /><![endif]-->
<!-- /Stylesheets -->
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- /Scripts -->
<!-- Meta Tags -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<!-- /Meta Tags -->
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="bgstripe"></div>
<div id="outercontainer">
    <div class="leftbar"></div>
    <div id="innercontainer">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="leftbar"></div>
            <div class="innercontent">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div>
                <span class="articletitle">Page Title!</span>
                <div class="articletitlebar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="articletext"><p>
                Put your text here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="faderight"></div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    overflow: auto;
}

#bgstripe {
    float: left;
    background-color: #67a7ff;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

#faderight {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background: url('../images/layout/fade-right.jpg');
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}

#outercontainer {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2a5d95;
}

#innercontainer {
    position: fixed;
    float:left;
    width: 950px;
    background-color: #2a5d95;
}

.leftbar {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('../images/layout/leftbar.png');
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}

.innercontent {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: #2a5d95;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 950px;
    height: 200px;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.articletitle {
    background-color: #003366;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: #eeeeee;
}

.articletitlebar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url('../images/layout/articletitlebar.png');
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.articletext {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Anyone who can help me with this? I'm totally lost right now..
Online sample: http://rune.blupfis.nl/wendy/

Comment: Do you have an online sample we can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position:fixed on #innercontainer is part of the problem, if not the whole issue. That will act like an absolutely positioned element and be removed from the normal flow.

Comment: yep, on the innercontainer `position:absolute` fixes the scroll but screws up the layout at the bottom. i think you should look for online samples of this layout.

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that.. Scrollbars appearing now! :)

Comment: Small problem still: When scrolling down, the bottom will be white.. Any idea how to fix it? Can't find that problem either :S

Comment: @Rune - Don't have my tools with me now. You probably should start a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the height of your `contentdiv` is set to 100%.  This makes it expand so that it is the same height as its contents.  If you try something more like this:

```
#content {
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

you should see the scroll bars appearing (but some other styling may be lost now).